# Trying to create child Account record whenever a new Account is created

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist, account, clone

Instead of someone clicking on "Clone" button on an Account , we are trying to automate this process whenever a new Account is created. We need child account picklist field value filled in when creating using flow. I am trying to debug my flow and didn;t hit any errors but i am not seeing child account created on the Actual account where i am triggering the flow to happen in debug mode. Please help how i can achieve this.

Flow Type: Record triggered flow

Flow Trigger: When a new Account is created with a "X" picklist field value as "NO" (This is the Parent Account)

After Save
Create Child Account with a "X" picklist field value as "YES"

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are your trigger conditions and what is the "When to run the flow" option?

Comment: Whenever a new Account is created i need to create child account...Basically it is clone functionality, but we would like to happen with a flow and not someone clicking on "Clone" button

Comment: Yes, but specifically in your flow, what the trigger conditions for the flow to run and when are you running it: before save or after save?

Comment: Flow is record triggered flow and i am creating child record after save

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  The new child account cause your Flow  trigger your flow to create a child below that, in an infinite loop.  You should [edit] your post to include your trigger conditions and include more details about your issue.

Comment: You still need to provide more detail.  What do you mean by Parent Account field value = No?  The Parent Account field cannot have a "No" value.